# how to make a dummy job to run for 30 minutes in controlm

Tags: control-m

I have the requirement to run dummy jobs for 30 minutes and 60 minutes respectively.

I have tried with `--delay 30` in command line jobs, but I did not get the expected delay.

Comment: can you please show the code you have tried?

Comment: Hi Caccin, Thanks for you comment. I tried with --delay 30 which did not worked.

Comment: I have updated your question with the code you have used, please put also the error you saw, in this way you will probably get an aswer quickly

Comment: A dummy job (as in a Control-M job that is set to "run as dummy" or just tasktype = dummy) will not execute anything. It will just turn green/ok. Running jobs like this is meant to be a placeholder in the flow. You need to run your job as tasktype = command. If on Windows use Control-M utility _sleep (i.e. **_sleep 600** will sleep for 10 minutes or **sleep 600** on Unix).

Comment: You could even use the Agent **_sleep** command, which has the advantage of working the same way regardless of the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Designating a job as type ‘dummy’ will bypass anything contained within the command line field.

You have two options to create a 30/60minute timer job.

Option a:
Make the job a command line type job and put `sleep 1800` or `sleep 3600` in the command line field.

Option b:
Make the job a dummy type job and put `sleep 1800` or `sleep 3600` in either the pre-execution or post-execution fields.

By default the sleep command operates on seconds. For windows you may want to look into using the power shell version which would be `powershell.exe -command start-sleep 1800`

Answer (score 1):

## Use *_sleep* over *sleep* instead

Another way to enable a waiting time, either before or after an **OS-type Job** is by using the **pre-execution** or **post-execution** command options, as appropriate.

The use of **_sleep** is more convenient because it is operating system independent and is provided by the Control-M/Agent, which means that you do not require an extra deployment for that functionality.